# increase the post_max_size in live server php

Tags: php, .htaccess, configuration

I want to change the `post_max_size` in live server, for that I have created a file say `.htaccess` with following data

```
php_value post_max_size 100M
```

and placed this `.htaccess` file in root folder of the project.
This worked in local but not working at live Server. Where did I make mistake, please suggest me in right way to increase the `post_max_size` in live server.

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: `ini_set('post_max_size','100M');` according to php documentation located here: https://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: @user3647971 , this is not working even in local

Comment: Did you put it in .htaccess or the php file you are trying to run?

Comment: should be done through php.ini  why .htaccess?

Comment: @SayedMohdAli yes it should be done through php.ini in local but in live server i dont have access to cpanel so how to achieve it

Comment: In .htaccess you can restrict portions of the application which have higher max post size, also with php ini_set function same principle. All of those exists just because they offer different scopes to achieve this

Comment: in my live server the `post_max_size` is set to 8MB ,I want to increase this by coding

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size I was just pointing out that you might need to change this environment variable aswell

Comment: Remember that .htaccess file works on the scope it is defined in and how your apache is configured. Apache looks for the file inside folder where your request is forwarded

Answer (score 1):

open .htaccess add this line.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 99M
php_value post_max_size 100M
```

If your web server is running php5, I believe you must use `php5_value`.

for some hosting like Web Fusion, you need to create a file called php.ini and save it in the same location as your .htaccess file.

your method is right, check your .htaccess file is updated successfully or not also,

`upload_max_filesize` should be less than `post_max_size`.

If you are getting 500 - Internal server error that means you don't have permission to set these values by .htaccess. You have to contact your web server providers and ask to set AllowOverride Options for your host or to put these lines in their virtual host configuration file.

Comment: `upload_max_filesize` in live server has set to 200MB. I dont have any problem with it but I want to change `post_max_size`.you are saying that i have to add two lines in `.htaccess` with `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`?

Comment: upload_max_filesize should be less than post_max_size

Comment: if it is 200M than make post_max_size 201M

Comment: still not working.As my code is `php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
php_value post_max_size 201M` and but it still showing `post_max_size` as 8M and `upload_max_size` as 200M

Comment: check your .htaccess is successfully update or not, also check it is working or not 
type anything like aosdjosajdasjdoajsdao in .htaccess to check it is working.

Comment: no .htaccess file is not wroking in live server but working in local.What should i do

Comment: open the Apache configuration file (typically either called httpd.conf or apache.conf) and check that the AllowOverride directive is set to AllowOverride All.

Comment: after making changes sudo service apache2 restart